# Vocal sounds library suggestions

Tags: sound-libraries

I'm looking for a comprehensive vocal sounds library that I can purchase royalty free. I'd like it to include various age people recorded when laughing, crying, humming, grunting etc.

Up to now I've been hiring voice actors to record this stuff for me, and it was more or less all right. I've also found excellent such recordings in Bottle Rocket FX Scream Collection, but it only has recordings done by mature actors.

Lately I find myself in need of various age kids' laughs, cries and other utterings that makes hiring voice actors too time consuming.

I know that boutique sound libraries are often hidden on the 10th page of Google search because of poor SEO, and this is why I'm asking this question in here. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Blastwave FX has a collection of "Power Packs" priced at $25 each - I believe there are a total of 16 individual packs, each with various types of human elements - coughing, laughing, eating, moaning and groaning, children, babies, etc.  May be what you're looking for.

http://www.blastwavefx.com/Humans/c66/index.html?osCsid=7gk1jg6ar9plilidob33gtt4r2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did get two of those packs, and I bookmarked the page. One thing I could use more of is teenager voices though. Seems like everybody has babies and adults, but nothing in between.